# Can't find kernel.log file on Yosemite

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extensions

I began kernel programming on mac.

Because I want to run my kernel extensions without code signing I had to do the following:

```
sudo nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=1
```

It works as it should be, but the problem is that I can't find my kernel.log file.

I opened Console app and even there under FILES there is no kernel.log, I have listed all the other files except that one.

Any suggestions where can I find my kernel.log file?

I need it for debug purposes.

Answer (score 1):

On Yosemite, those kernel messages should be logged to `System.log` according to `/etc/asl.conf`, which replaced the older `syslog.conf`. Apple System Logger and Syslog both use `/etc/asl.conf`

```
 # Rules for /var/log/system.log 
 > system.log mode=0640 format=bsd rotate=seq compress file_max=5M all_max=50M
 ? [= Sender kernel] file system.log
```

Kernel.log is not used by any logger since 10.8 I believe, but confirmed in 10.10.x

Note, El Capitan and *SIP* removed support for `kext-dev-mode`, so keep that in mind if you need to debug in newer OS X versions.

Comment: Do you have any idea why simple `printf()` doesn't get logged? I load the example with `sudo kextload`, then check with `kextstat` if it was loaded and it is and then I unload the example with `sudo kextunload` and again check if everything is OK - and it is.

Comment: In OSX `10.9.5` I can't find `/var/log/kernel.log`, so it seems to be removed also in that version. So it makes sense that it was removed in `10.8`.